# Compiling project on a remote machine by SSH

Tags: svn, macos, ssh, virtual-machine

I have several virtual machines on amazon, and I am only able to compile my project on these machines, because they are preconfigured and are deployed from special template. I often have some work with merging branches(SVN) and after merging each issue I need to compile the project on a remote VDI, and then check how it works. I use Mac OS at the moment, so I want to use my local software for merging, and then have these merged updates to be compiled on the VDI automatically. Something like a SVN utility with SSH support. I merge files locally and they are automatically moved to VDI.

Anyone, Do you know any mac software for SVN that allows to use remote ssh machine?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a svn software, but you could mount the files via sshfs and do your work on your local machine but with the data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

@Gauchi's answer is a lightweight solution. The below is over and above that:

You can use a personal build server ( [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Go](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management) etc. ) and have the remote machines as agents looking at the SVN repo that you checkin to and have them compile it. Might be a bit heavy weight for what you want, but you get other benefits and you can have a CI setup running as well.